# condiciones con if y else

Tags: javascript, condiciones

necesito cambiar la clase de una imagen if y else. en primer lugar al dar clic la imagen crece pero no he podido regresarla a la clase "small".

[image: uso de if y else]

Comment: Realmente no se entiende.

Answer (score -1):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

By add toggle you can solve the issue and can go back to the previous big image.
codes are following here:

```
<img onclick="myFunction()" id="smart_thumbnail" class="big" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/01/22/19/44/flower-field-250016__340.jpg" alt="">

<!-- css code -->
<style>
    .big{
        width:525px;
        height: 470px;
    }
    
    .small {
        width:300px;
        height: 275px;
    }
</style>


<!-- Javascript code -->
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var thumbnailElement = document.getElementById("smart_thumbnail");
        thumbnailElement.classList.toggle("small");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Recuerda que estás en [es.so]. Además, evita responder a preguntas de baja calidad, en donde el OP (autor de la pregunta) no explica claramente el problema.